# Stop Android Studio commenting out lines pasted under comment

Tags: android-studio, comments, settings

Within the past week or so Android Studio (3.1.3) has started auto-commenting out any lines I paste directly under a single-line comment. For example, if I need to move bar() and baz() before foo() in this code:

```
// Do a thing
foo();

...

bar();
baz();
```

and I cut and paste the lines to the new location, I get this:

```
// Do a thing
//    bar();
//    baz();
foo();

...
```

Dropping a new line after a comment before doing a paste will work as it did before, but either way it's disruptive.

I don't see anything obvious in settings.
Does anyone know a way to disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest Android Studio updates this behaviour has reverted to the previous behaviour, not commenting out pasted lines.